# Send silent push notification to app, update location and send to server in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, background-task, background-fetch

I want to send a silent push notification to an application that is in background, then fetch the current user location and send it to a web service.

I implemented push notification methods and also those two:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSDate *fetchStart = [NSDate date];

    [self sendLocationToServerWithCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
        completionHandler(result);

        NSDate *fetchEnd = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = [fetchEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:fetchStart];
        NSLog(@"Background Fetch Duration: %f seconds", timeElapsed);

    }];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{

}
```

I've also created a method that will send the location to the server:

```
- (void)sendLocationToServerWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"UserId"      : self.userId,
                             @"Latitude"    : self.latitude,
                             @"Longitude"   : self.longitude
                             }

    ServerManager *manager = [ServerManager sharedManager];
    [manager sendLocationToServerWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {

        if (success)
        {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
        }
        else
        {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
        }

    }];
}
```

I just can't understand how they all work together, will Apple approve that, is it even possible and where does the location background fetch goes into.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes its possible, and I've an app in the app store that does exactly that so yes Apple will approve it. But apart from that, it is not clear what your actual question is. You've shown two disparate small pieces of code that have no relation to each other as things stand. Are you asking people to finish your program for you?

Comment: No, of course not, I'm asking someone to guide me on how to do it, show me a tutorial how to combine the three background tasks that I want together because I'm really confused and doesn't have a clue how to do it.. And thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a brief sketch of what you can do to give you an idea. Its assuming there is a model class implemented as a singleton and there's some pseudo code.

```
// App delegate
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    [[YourModel singleton] pushNotificationReceived: userInfo];
}

// Model
- (void)  pushNotificationReceived:(NSDictionary *) userInfo
{
    [self registerBackgroundTaskHandler];
    get the location here, or start getting the location
    [self sendLocationToServerWithCompletionHandler: your completion handler];
}


- (void) registerBackgroundTaskHandler
{
    __block UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    self.backgroundTaskId = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        DDLogInfo(@"BACKGROUND  Background task expiration handler called");
        [app endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskId];
        self.backgroundTaskId = 0;
    }];
}


- (void) endBackgroundTask
{
    if (self.backgroundTaskId)
    {
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [app endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskId];
        self.backgroundTaskId = 0;
    }
}
```

You'll need to get the location before you can send it. If you are just getting one location and you're using iOS9 you can use CLLocationManager:requestLocation: and you could fit this in relatively easily into where I've said "get the location here".

If you're not using iOS 9 (requestLocation is new with iOS 9) its a bit more complex.
How to use the location manager is a topic in itself and too much code to post here. You need to read and study all about using the location manger before you can incorporate it.
If you need a stream of location updates it gets more complex and where it says "or start getting the location" is a lot more involved then is implied in the pseudo code.

My recommendation, start with iOS9 and getting one instance of the location, then when thats working, add more functionality or iOS8 support if you need it.

Comment: Well, my problem is that I'm using iOS6 to IOS9, so I need to support location service for all those versions, but that's fine, I know how to do it. I just need to fetch the location once and send it to server - that's it. My problem was with the location, push and sending to server, but I'll create a new project and start messing with it tomorrow. Thanks alot!

Comment: Unfortunately there's a problem with this whole approach though if you need the location instantly. From iOS 6 to 8.1 it'll be fine. But starting with iOS 8.2 Apple have made changes and the result is that very often your silent push will not be delivered to you app in a timely manner, sometimes it will, but often it may be delayed by several hours. And there's nothing you can do to fix that. (If you do experiments to check this out, make sure your iPhone has no cables plugged in of any sort, including a connection to Xcode via usb)

Comment: Why is that? What changes they have made?

Comment: Its to conserve power, but they seem to have done it in a bad way, even if the device is 100% charged the push often will be delayed for several hours. I haven't yet experimented with iOS 9 but with iOS8 it makes silent push totally unusable if you need your app to get it quickly.